# A sports club has 3 departments, tennis, squash and badminton

Tags: combinatorics

The question is:

A sports club has 3 departments, tennis, squash and badminton. We get
given the following information.

• 90 people are members of the tennis department.

• 60 people are members of the squash department.

• 70 people are members of the badminton department.

• 25 people are members of both the tennis department and the squash department.

• 15 people are members of both the tennis department and the badminton department.

• 13 people are members of both the squash department and the badminton department.

• 4 people are members of all 3 departments.

**How many different members does the sports club have?**

I can not see the idea of how to solve it. Had there not been "repetition" then it would have been another talk. Anyone who can give hints? Am I correct if I think about of this formula?
$C(n,r)=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$
Update: I might be wrong with the formula, since there is repetition. 
I believe it's
$\frac{(n+r-1)!}{r!(n-1)!}$

Answer (score 1):

Start by drawing a Venn diagram like this:

[image]

where each circle represents one department. Now, start putting in numbers in the regions one by one as you can figure them out, letting each number represent the number of students in that exact region. Many of the numbers you have been given are actually the sum of the numbers in multiple regions, so you can't fill them in immediately. The only thing you can fill in initially is that center region where all circles overlap, which should have $4$ in it.

Next, there are $13$ people who do squash and badminton. That means that the two regions where the squash and badminton circles overlap (one region is where they also overlap the tennis circle, and one where they don't) should have $13$ in total. Since you already have $4$ in one region, that leaves $9$ for the part of the squash-badminton overlap which is outside the tennis circle.

Keep going like this, and eventually you will have filled each region with a number representing exactly how many are in each group.

Comment: I understand what you mean when you took the "Badminton Squash" which have 13 members, and I've also used 4 hence we have 9.

So am I correct with "Badminton Tennis" with 11 members and "Tennis Squash" with 21 members?

Comment: @M.Rasmussen Yes, you're right. Specifically, Badminton-Tennis-Not Squash has $11$ members, and similarily for Tennis-Squash-Not Badminton, which will have $21$.

Comment: Ahh great! So if I have to find the total amount of tennis players, I have to subtract 21, 11 and 4? I'm not sure about number 4 since we already dealt with it before.

Comment: @M.Rasmussen No, you're entirely right. The $90$ members of the tennis department consists of $4$ triple-members and $11+21$ double-members, so to find the number of single-members, you have to subtract all of those.

Comment: So there are total 126 members in the sport club?

Comment: @M.Rasmussen That sounds a bit low, but I haven't actually checked myself.

Comment: Tennis: 90-21-11-4=54
Squash: 60-21-4-9=26
Badminton: 70-11-9=46
Total: 54+26+46=126

Comment: @M.Rasmussen That total only contains the single-members. You haven't added the students who are member of two or all three clubs (yes, there is a lot of the same numbers being added then subtracted then added back in this argument).

Comment: Okay, what I understand from your comment is that I have to add all the members from both departments. i.e. (Squash and Tennis and so on), so my answer is:
https://puu.sh/zBLjD/c13a1383ff.png

I hope it make sence

Comment: @M.Rasmussen yeah, that looks right.

Answer (score 1):

Let $B$ denote the number of people who play badminton; let $S$ denote the number of people who play squash; let $T$ denote the number of people who play tennis.  The number of people in the club is the number of people who play one of these sports, which by the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), is 
$$|B \cup S \cup T| = |B| + |S| + |T| - |B \cap S| - |B \cap T| - |S \cap T| + |B \cap S \cap T|$$
Why should this be the case?

If we simply add up the members who play badminton, squash, or tennis, we will count each person who plays two sports twice, once for each sport they play.  We only want to count them once, so we must subtract the number who play two sports from the total $|B| + |S| + |T|$.  However, if they play three sports, we have both added them three times, once for each sport they play, and subtracted them three times, once for each pair of sports they play.  Hence, the quantity $$|B| + |S| + |T| - |B \cap S| - |B \cap T| - |S \cap T|$$ does not count those who play three sports at all.  Thus, we need to add the number of people who play all three sports to $|B| + |S| + |T| - |B \cap S| - |B \cap T| - |S \cap T|$ to account for them.

Answer (score 0):

Just set up a Venn diagram with $3$ circles, and place a variable in each of the $7$ bounded regions.

Note that you have $7$ pieces of given information, each of which yields a linear equation.

Thus, you'll have $7$ linear equations in $7$ unknowns.

Of course, if some piece of information just gives an immediate value for a given region, then you don't need a variable for that region or an equation for that piece of information.

Solve the system, and you'll easily get the required answer.

Comment: So I've set up a venn diagram but how can I set up equations? I can't see the point right now

Comment: Draw the diagram, with circles $T,B,S$ representing Tennis, Badminton, and Squash, respectively. Let the variables be represented by multi-character names, so for example, the variable $tb$ is the count of people in $T$ and $B$, but not in $S$, and the variable $ts$ is the count of people in $T$ and $S$, but not in $B$, and the variable $t$ is the count of people in $T$, but not in $B$ or $S$. Then, the first piece of information (together with the last piece) yields the equation $t+tb + ts + 4 = 90$.

Comment: In both a practical and theoretical sense, N. F. Taussig's answer is a perfect for this problem, since the given information fills in all the terms of the RHS of the formula, and the LHS is what you want to find. No variables, no equations, no mess, no fuss. That said, the method I proposed, while pedestrian, would work for problems where the given information was not a perfect fit for the inclusion-exclusion formula, and it's reasonably practical (assuming only $3$ circles).

Answer (score 0):

The idea of setting the Venn diagram (mentioned before) is very good, but I will modify it a bit:

Set it to $7$ regions like below ($T$ is for tennis, $S$ is for squash, $B$ is for badminton)

Assume the number of people in each region is $a_{1},a_{2},a_{3},a_{4},a_{5},a_{6},a_{7}$. I will state again the seven statements:

• $90$ people are members of the tennis department.

• $60$ people are members of the squash department.

• $70$ people are members of the badminton department.

• $25$ people are members of both the tennis department and the squash department.

• $15$ people are members of both the tennis department and the badminton department.

• $13$ people are members of both the squash department and the badminton department.

• $4$ people are members of all 3 departments.

[image]

We have this set of equations (respectively for each of the statements):

${\begin{cases}a_1+a_2+a_4+a_7=90\\a_2+a_3+a_5+a_7=60\\a_4+a_5+a_6+a_7=70\\a_2+a_7=25\\a_4+a_7=15\\a_5+a_7=13\\a_7=4\end{cases}}$

Replace $a_7=4$ for all the equations above, we will have:

${\begin{cases}a_1+a_2+a_4=86\\a_2+a_3+a_5=56\\a_4+a_5+a_6=66\\a_2=21\\a_4=11\\a_5=9\\a_7=4\end{cases}} \Rightarrow{\begin{cases}a_1+21+11=86\\21+a_3+9=56\\11+9+a_6=66\\a_2=21\\a_4=11\\a_5=9\\a_7=4\end{cases}} \Rightarrow{\begin{cases}a_1=54\\a_3=26\\a_6=46\\a_2=21\\a_4=11\\a_5=9\\a_7=4\end{cases}} $

That set of seven equations can be solved much quickly than you (and I) thought.

The number of different members in this sport club is:

$a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}+a_{4}+a_{5}+a_{6}+a_{7}=54+21+26+11+9+46+4=171$